# forward declaration of smth that represents the list of elements

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, forward-declaration

What should I do to declare forward `A`, that represents a list of elements `B`, each of which refers to the `C`, that `boost::recursive_wrapper`-s to the `A`?

Especially interested in case of when all the types are templated ones. Say,

```
template< typename F > struct expression 
   : tagged, boost::spirit::extended_variant< 
           nil, 
           F, 
           boost::recursive_wrapper< expression_list< F > 
         > > 
   {...};
```

then *what should be the **expression_list**?*:

```
template< typename F > struct expression;
template< typename F >
using expression_list = std::list< expression< F > >;
... // definition of template< typename F > expression; here
```

cannot be used in `boost::recursive_wrapper`'s template parameter list, but in case of

```
template< typename F >
struct expression_list;
... // definition of template< typename F > expression; here
template< typename F >
struct expression_list
    : std::list< expression< F > >
{ ; }
```

there is `static_assert(!std::has_virtual_destructor< std::list< expression< F > > >::value, "has virtual destructor")` and, therefore, cannot be used too.

Comment: Hmmm? It is exceptionally unclear how you are planning on using... anything really. Why don't you post code with comments, instead of "prose" that describes the code you don't show?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but the following sample definition ***with*** usage examples seems to work fine for me (consider making the conversion constructor `explicit` in real life, though):

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_extended_variant.hpp>

struct nil{};

template< typename F > struct expression;
template< typename F >
using expression_list = std::list< expression< F > >;

template< typename F >
using expression_base = boost::spirit::extended_variant<
           nil, 
           F, 
           boost::recursive_wrapper< expression_list< F > 
         > >;

template< typename F > 
struct expression : expression_base<F>
   {
       template <typename I>
           expression(I&& i) 
           : expression_base<F>(std::forward<I>(i)) 
       {}

       expression(std::initializer_list<F> l) 
           : expression_base<F>(expression_list<F>{l}) {}
   };


int main()
{
    auto v = expression<int> (42);
    v = expression<int> { 1, 2, 3, 42 };

    v = 43;
    v = { 2, 3, 4, 43 };
}
```